# How can I create a sparse matrix instead of a dense one in this program?

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I have this delta function which have 3 cases. `mask1`, `mask2` and if none of them is satisfied `delta = 0`, since `res = np.zeros`

```
def delta(r, dr):
    res = np.zeros(r.shape)
    mask1 = (r >= 0.5*dr) & (r <= 1.5*dr)
    res[mask1] = (5-3*np.abs(r[mask1])/dr \
        - np.sqrt(-3*(1-np.abs(r[mask1])/dr)**2+1)) \
        /(6*dr)
    mask2 = np.logical_not(mask1) & (r <= 0.5*dr)
    res[mask2] = (1+np.sqrt(-3*(r[mask2]/dr)**2+1))/(3*dr)
    return res
```

Then I have this other function where I call the former and I construct an array, `E`

```
def matrix_E(nk,X,Y,xhi,eta,dx,dy):
   rx =  abs(X[np.newaxis,:] - xhi[:,np.newaxis])
   ry =  abs(Y[np.newaxis,:] - eta[:,np.newaxis])
   deltx = delta(rx,dx)
   delty = delta(ry,dy)
   E = deltx*delty
   return E
```

The thing is that most of the elements of `E` belong to the third case of delta, 0. Most means about 99%.
So, I would like to have a sparse matrix instead of a dense one and not to stock the 0 elements in order to save memory.

Any ideas in how I could do it?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) submodule?

Comment: Of course I do, but I dont know how to use it in this case. I dont want to convert the dense array to a sparse one, but directly create the sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to create a sparse matrix is to construct three 1d arrays, with the nonzero values, and their `i` and `j` indexes.  Then pass them to the `coo_matrix` function.

The coordinates don't have to be in order, so you could construct the arrays for the 2 nonzero mask cases and concatenate them.

Here's a sample construction using 2 masks

```
In [107]: x=np.arange(5)

In [108]: i,j,data=[],[],[]

In [110]: mask1=x%2==0
In [111]: mask2=x%2!=0

In [112]: i.append(x[mask1])
In [113]: j.append((x*2)[mask1])

In [114]: i.append(x[mask2])
In [115]: j.append(x[mask2])

In [116]: i=np.concatenate(i)
In [117]: j=np.concatenate(j)

In [118]: i
Out[118]: array([0, 2, 4, 1, 3])

In [119]: j
Out[119]: array([0, 4, 8, 1, 3])

In [120]: M=sparse.coo_matrix((x,(i,j)))

In [121]: print(M)
  (0, 0)    0
  (2, 4)    1
  (4, 8)    2
  (1, 1)    3
  (3, 3)    4

In [122]: M.A
Out[122]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]])
```

A `coo` format stores those 3 arrays as is, but they get sorted and cleaned up when converted to other formats and printed.

I can work on adapting this to your case, but this may be enough to get you started.

---

It looks like `X,Y,xhi,eta` are 1d arrays.  `rx` and `ry` are then 2d.  `delta` returns a result the same shape as its input.  `E = deltx*delty` suggests that `deltax` and `deltay` are the same shape (or at least broadcastable).

Since sparse matrix has a `.multiply` method to do element wise multiplication, we can focus on producing sparse `delta` matrices.

If you afford the memory to make `rx`, and a couple of masks, then you can also afford to make `deltax` (all the same size).  Even through `deltax` has lots of zeros, it is probably fastest to make it dense.

But let's try to case the `delta` calculation, as a sparse build.

This looks like the essense of what you are doing in `delta`, at least with one mask:

start with a 2d array:

```
In [138]: r = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)    
In [139]: mask1 = (r>=8) & (r<=16)
In [140]: res1 = r[mask1]*0.2
In [141]: I,J = np.where(mask1)
```

the resulting vectors are:

```
In [142]: I
Out[142]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32)    
In [143]: J
Out[143]: array([2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
In [144]: res1
Out[144]: array([ 1.6,  1.8,  2. ,  2.2,  2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ,  3.2])
```

Make a sparse matrix:

```
In [145]: M=sparse.coo_matrix((res1,(I,J)), r.shape)    
In [146]: M.A
Out[146]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1.6,  1.8,  2. ,  2.2],
       [ 2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ,  3.2,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

I could make another sparse matrix with `mask2`, and add the two.

```
In [147]: mask2 = (r>=17) & (r<=22)    
In [148]: res2 = r[mask2]*-0.4
In [149]: I,J = np.where(mask2)
In [150]: M2=sparse.coo_matrix((res2,(I,J)), r.shape)
In [151]: M2.A
Out[151]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. , -6.8],
       [-7.2, -7.6, -8. , -8.4, -8.8,  0. ]])

...
In [153]: (M1+M2).A
Out[153]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1.6,  1.8,  2. ,  2.2],
       [ 2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ,  3.2, -6.8],
       [-7.2, -7.6, -8. , -8.4, -8.8,  0. ]])
```

Or I could concatenate the `res1` and `res2`, etc and make one sparse matrix:

```
In [156]: I1,J1 = np.where(mask1)
In [157]: I2,J2 = np.where(mask2)
In [158]: res12=np.concatenate((res1,res2))
In [159]: I12=np.concatenate((I1,I2))
In [160]: J12=np.concatenate((J1,J2))
In [161]: M12=sparse.coo_matrix((res12,(I12,J12)), r.shape)

In [162]: M12.A
Out[162]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1.6,  1.8,  2. ,  2.2],
       [ 2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ,  3.2, -6.8],
       [-7.2, -7.6, -8. , -8.4, -8.8,  0. ]])
```

Here I choose the masks so the nonzero values don't overlap, but both methods work if they did.  It's a delibrate design feature of the `coo` format that values for repeated indices are summed.  It's very handy feature when creating sparse matries for finite element problems.

---

I can also get index arrays by creating a sparse matrix from the mask:

```
In [179]: rmask1=sparse.coo_matrix(mask1)

In [180]: rmask1.row
Out[180]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int32)

In [181]: rmask1.col
Out[181]: array([2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
In [184]: sparse.coo_matrix((res1, (rmask1.row, rmask1.col)),rmask1.shape).A
Out[184]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1.6,  1.8,  2. ,  2.2],
       [ 2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ,  3.2,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

I can't, though, create a mask from a sparse version of `r`.  `(r>=8) & (r<=16)`.  That kind of inequality test has not been implemented for sparse matrices.  But that might not matter, since `r` is probably not sparse.

Comment: I get the idea. However in your example, when you do i.append(x[mask2]) you are getting the value of x, but I would need the coordinate. How could I do it? Thanks

Comment: In the code that I just added, I used `np.where` to get the coordinates of the nonzero items.

Comment: Just excellent. I ve been able to do exactly what I want thank to your help. For your info it takes the same time to do the dense array and the sparse one. I have checked for different sizes of X,Y and xhi,eta